# how can I add if condition for ViewData metatag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I use Layout ViewData["Description"] on some pages and on some pages I don't use ViewData["Description"] how can I add if condition here

[image]

```
@{
   
 @if (bool.Parse(ViewData["Description"].ToString()))
    {
        @ViewData["Description"]
    }
    else
    {
        "Bilgisayarınızda yaşadığınız her türlü teknik sorunu çözmek için profesyonel bir çözüm arıyorsanız, doğru yerdesiniz."
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it appears that you're trying to do `bool.Parse()` on a value that will never pass as a boolean, so get rid of that. Instead, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` and assign `ViewData["Description"]` to a variable:

```cs
    @{
        var description = "Bilgisayarınızda yaşadığınız her türlü teknik sorunu çözmek için profesyonel bir çözüm arıyorsanız, doğru yerdesiniz.";
    
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)ViewData["Description"]))
        {
            description = (string)ViewData["Description"];
        }
    }
```

Then reference the variable in your meta element:

```html
    <meta name="description" content="@description" />
```

Comment: kod çalıştı teşekkür ederim, string.IsNullOrEmpty() şeklinde kullanacağım